# Skype OAuth Tokens are unavailable

Tags: skype, ucwa

I have a problem. Whenever I go to ucwa.skype.com and sign in, I always get redirected to an error page and appear to be not signed in. But then if I again go to ucwa.skype.com/code, I am signed in but the tokens are not available. Instead I get ‘Data unavailable, try again’.
Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've seen that few days ago; and also seen similar issues sometimes in the past.
It is probably some problem with the application to run behind, so only MS can resolve that (with a restart? :))

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be something like this. :)